# Solubility of Ag2S in excess sodium thiosulphate solution

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

The question is pretty much self-explanatory,I wanted to know whether Ag2S dissolves in excess hypo solution.Given that we know AgBr dissolves in hypo forming a complex I expected the same complex to form here,but a question in a textbook I follow says it isnt.I'd like to know why.

Answer (score 2):

The ion $\ce{Ag+}$ may react with $\ce{S2O3^{2-}}$ or with $\ce{S^{2-}}$ according to

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{Ag^+ + 2 S2O3^{2-} &-> [Ag(S2O3)_2]^{3-}} &\quad K_1 &= \pu{1.7E-13} \label{rxn:1}\tag{R1}\\
\ce{2 Ag^+ + S^{2-} &-> Ag2S} &\quad K_\mathrm{s} &= \pu{6.3E-51} \label{rxn:2}\tag{R2}
\end{align}
$$

So, if the reacting ions $\ce{S2O3^{2-}}$ and $\ce{S^{2-}}$ are both in concentration $\pu{1 M}$, the remaining ion $\ce{Ag+}$ would have a residual concentration equal to $\pu{6E-14 M}$ according to \eqref{rxn:1}, and $\pu{8E-25 M}$ according to \eqref{rxn:2}. So as soon as $[\ce{Ag+}] < 10^{-13},$ the ion $\ce{Ag+}$ does not react according to \eqref{rxn:1}, but it reacts according to \eqref{rxn:2}.

When dissolving pure $\ce{Ag2S}$ in water, the concentration of $\ce{Ag^+}$ is

$$c(\ce{Ag^+}) = \left(\frac{\pu{6.3E-51}}{4}\right)^{1/3} = \pu{1.1E-17 M},$$

which is much too low to produce any reaction according to \eqref{rxn:1}.

Answer (score 1):

In aqueous solutions, $\ce{Ag2S }$ is practically insoluble:
$$\ce{Ag2S (s) + H2O (l) <=> 2 Ag^+  (aq) + S^{2-} (aq) }  \tag{1}$$
with
$$K_\mathrm{sp} = [\ce{Ag+}]^2[\ce{S^2-}] = \pu{6.3E-50} \tag{2}$$
When excess of aqueous $\ce{S2O3^2-}$ is added, following complex formation reaction would taken place:
$$\ce{Ag+ (aq) + 2 S2O3^2- (aq) <=> [Ag(S2O3)2]^3- (aq)}   \tag{3}$$
with
$$K_\mathrm{f_1} = \frac{[\ce{[Ag(S2O3)2]^3-}]}{[\ce{Ag+}][\ce{S2O3^2-}]^2}= \pu{2.0E13} \tag{4}$$
The net reaction can be obtained by the sum of the equations $(1) + 2 \times (3)$:

$$\ce{Ag2S (aq) + 4 S2O3^2- (aq) <=> 2[Ag(S2O3)2]^3- (aq) + S^2- (aq) } \tag{5}$$

Thus,
$$K_\mathrm{net} = \frac{[\ce{[Ag(S2O3)2]^3-}]^2[\ce{S^2-}]}{[\ce{S2O3^2-}]^4}= \frac{[\ce{[Ag(S2O3)2]^3-}]^2}{[\ce{Ag+}]^2[\ce{S2O3^2-}]^4} \times [\ce{Ag+}]^2[\ce{S^2-}] \\ = K_\mathrm{f_1}^2 \times K_\mathrm{sp} = \left(\pu{2.0E13}\right)^2 \times \pu{6.3E-50} = \pu{2.5E-23}$$

Thus, adding an aqueous solution of $\ce{S2O3^2-}$ in excess will produce a higher concentration of the complex ion in solution according to the equation $(5)$ and thus the solubility of $\ce{Ag2S}$ will be much higher in an aqueous $\ce{S2O3^2-}$ solution $(K_\mathrm{net} = \pu{2.5E-23})$ than that in water $(K_\mathrm{sp} = \pu{6.3E-50})$.

---

**Note:** $(K_\mathrm{sp} = \pu{5.0E-13})$ for $\ce{AgBr}$:
$$\ce{AgBr (s) + H2O (l) <=> Ag^+  (aq) + Br- (aq) }  $$
Thus, when excess amount of aqueous $\ce{S2O3^2-}$ is added to $\ce{AgBr}$, same complex formation reaction would taken place:
$$\ce{Ag+ (aq) + 2 S2O3^2- (aq) <=> [Ag(S2O3)2]^3- (aq)}   $$

Similar to $\ce{AgS}$, The net reaction can be obtained by the sum of above equations:

$$\ce{AgBr (aq) + 2 S2O3^2- (aq) <=> [Ag(S2O3)2]^3- (aq) + Br- (aq) } \tag{5}$$
Thus,
$$K_\mathrm{net} = \frac{[\ce{[Ag(S2O3)2]^3-}][\ce{Br-}]}{[\ce{S2O3^2-}]^2}= \frac{[\ce{[Ag(S2O3)2]^3-}]}{[\ce{Ag+}][\ce{S2O3^2-}]^2} \times [\ce{Ag+}][\ce{Br-}] \\ = K_\mathrm{f_1} \times K_\mathrm{sp} = \pu{2.0E13} \times \pu{5.0E-13} = \pu{1.0E1}$$

Here, $K_\mathrm{net} = \pu{1.0E1} \gt 1$ favoring forward direction, and therefore almost all of $\ce{AgBr}$ would dissolve.

Source for $K_\mathrm{f_1}$: [Source-1](https://lecturedemos.chem.umass.edu/solubility17_1.html) and [Source-2](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/General_Chemistry/Map%3A_General_Chemistry_(Petrucci_et_al.)/18%3A_Solubility_and_Complex-Ion_Equilibria/18.8%3A_Equilibria_Involving_Complex_Ions)